# ,"message":"jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I recently upgraded my springboot application from 2.7.9 to 3.1.0.When I start the application and hit api using swagger getting below error

```
ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getRequest()'
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1096)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ctl.bm.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>address-business-service</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <name>MicroService</name>
    <description>Micro Service</description>
        <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        <ch.qos.logback.version>1.4.7</ch.qos.logback.version>
        <!-- SONAR -->
        <sonar.analyses.mode>publish</sonar.analyses.mode>
        
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.login>286981679ecc4620b5f7e3786d96e2d09e710e85</sonar.login>
        <sonar.projectKey>bb_abs_scan</sonar.projectKey>
        <sonar.projectName>bb_abs</sonar.projectName>
        <sonar.issuesReport.html.enable>true</sonar.issuesReport.html.enable>
        <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2022.0.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-micrometer</artifactId>
            <version>13.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!--
         <dependency>
              <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
              <artifactId>javax.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.3</version>
         </dependency>
         -->
         <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId> <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>9.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.ctl.bm.exception</groupId> <artifactId>bmp-exception-module</artifactId> 
            <version>3.5.6</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version></version>
        </dependency>-->
         <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ctl.bm.exception</groupId>
      <artifactId>bmp-exception-module</artifactId>
      <version>22.12.01</version>
      <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ctl.bm.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>bmp-security-module</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.19</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ctl.bm.config</groupId>
            <artifactId>bmp-config-module</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SONAR -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1.1688</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- featuretoggles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
            <artifactId>togglz-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
            <artifactId>togglz-console</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
            <artifactId>togglz-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>



            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--<dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
                <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>PACKAGE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.0</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                <excludes>
                
                </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>rename-file</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>rename</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/site/jacoco/index.html</sourceFile>
                            <destinationFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static/coverage.html</destinationFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <goals>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Below is my maven dependency tree:

Comment: Please add your pom to the question. This comes from trying to manage conflicting dependencies, ofter from trying to outsmart the Spring Boot dependency management.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added pom,Please review it

Comment: `spring-cloud-dependencies` should go in `depenencyManagement` and that version isn't compatible afaik. Togglze version is not compatible either that is for Spring Boot 2. `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` should not have a version as you already use the `spring-cloud-dependencies` as an import. `jakarta.servlet-api` is already part of `spring-boot-starter-web`. The `junit` dependencies are part of `spring-boot-starter-test`, `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure` isn't needed. `sonar-maven-plugin` plugin as dependency?

Comment: @M.Deinum Tried everything you suggested still same issue.I guess some dependency is pointing to older version of org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getRequest() where it is expecting return type as javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest while the version that I have for ServletRequestAttributes in spring web is upgraded to rturnType jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Comment: Run a `mvn dependency:tree` and check the dependencies.

Comment: A lot of ancient old deps (junit 4, mockito 3.X), dependency to plugins, powermock not needed (better use mockito).. separate logback version (default in spring boot 2.X+) old version jacoco plugin, why copy plugin?...

Comment: @khmarbaise still no luck

Comment: To be honest there are so many things wrong in that setup...Trying to do things manually which are done by default.. JaCoCo etc. copy plugin etc.